# Square Filled CheckBox in Datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a Database that looks like this

Table Name : ri_closure
[image]

as what you see on the image above all of the columns except `Month` are `TinyInt(1)` and `Month` is `Varchar` now I have a code here

```
 Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.2.87;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
        Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from ri_closure", con1)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con1.Open()
        adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        con1.Close()
        ds1.Tables(0).Columns(2).DataType = GetType(Boolean)
        Me.DataGridView2.Columns(1).Frozen = True
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView2.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
        Next
        DataGridView2.Columns(0).Visible = False
        DataGridView2.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
```

Now this is what it looks like

[image]

Now you see the output and I'm sure you dont that want that red ones. Irritating in the eyes and here is my code for that

```
  For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            For ii As Integer = 2 To rw.Cells.Count - 1
                If rw.Cells(ii).Value = False Then
                    rw.Cells(ii).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                ElseIf rw.Cells(ii).Value = True Then
                    rw.Cells(ii).Style.BackColor = Color.White
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Now here is my question and I hope it is possible. I want to do something like this instead uncked and turn the cell in to red How can I make the uncked cell like this.

[image]

instead of empty checkbox it will look the same as the image above.

and another one I hope the that will generate filled checkbox will replace the uncheked value because I have code in checking of that one.

I try some code and this is the output

[image]

TYSM for future help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize painting of `DataGridViewCheckBox` column by handling [`CellPainting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`. Then you can use [`CheckBoxRenderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkboxrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw the check box in desired state. The state which you want to show for unchecked state of check box is [`CheckBoxState.MixedNormal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb177szy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Sub CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
        Dim value = DirectCast(e.FormattedValue, Nullable(Of Boolean))
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And _
                              Not (DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground))
        Dim state = IIf((value.HasValue And value.Value), _
                        VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal, _
                        VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal)
        Dim size = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, state)
        Dim location = New Point((e.CellBounds.Width - size.Width) / 2, _
                                (e.CellBounds.Height - size.Height) / 2)
        location.Offset(e.CellBounds.Location)
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, location, state)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To test the solution you can add a column to grid this way:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim C1 = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    C1.DataPropertyName = "C1"
    C1.HeaderText = "C1"
    C1.TrueValue = 1
    C1.FalseValue = 0
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(C1)
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DirectCast(1, Object))
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DirectCast(0, Object))
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
End Sub
```

And this will be the result:

[image]

To draw the unchecked (in fact mixed state) in red color, after calling `CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox` use this code:

```
If (state = VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal) Then
    Dim rect = New Rectangle(location, size)
    rect.Inflate(-2, -2)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect)
End If
```

[image]

Comment: Sir can you please encorporate your code on the form load on my code? please

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Form Load. Handle `CellPainting` event of grid.  `If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 ` means use custom paint logic for column at index 0.

Comment: I tried your code sir and the first 2nd column is the only row that has the right out put i will update my post sir

Comment: Don't update the question. If there is any problem ask here.

Comment: I got your question, in such cases if you edit the question the answer seems useless and the question will be confusing.

Comment: Sir only the f2nd column has the right output, I needed that all of the columns except `month` will have the same out put i put it in my post

Comment: Noted on that sir, This is my last update and I will focus on your answer

Comment: No problem, If you want to draw other columns this way, you need to change the criteria. For example: `If (e.ColumnIndex <> 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0)` This way, the logic will apply on all columns except the first one.

Comment: Or as another example: `If (((e.ColumnIndex = 1) Or (e.ColumnIndex = 2)) AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then` means use thelogic for column at index 1 and 2. If you learn the meaning of code, you can use any logic which you want.

Comment: `(e.RowIndex >= 0)` is because we want to render the column for rows of grid and not headers of columns. (e.ColumnIndex >= 1 And e.ColumnIndex<=12) means use the logic for 2nd to 13th columns.

Comment: Approve and + 1

Comment: Sir last one, Is there a possibility that instead of blue the filled one is color red something like that

Comment: Unfortunately not simply. `CheckBoxRenderer` doesn't support using different color than windows theme.

Comment: Oh my God, My boss is very conservative about this ,I thought he will be happy when he see it but then he wants it to red. He said "Its okay but I want it red"

Comment: You can fill the rectangle of checkbox by red color.

Comment: you mean my example right? the one in my post? my boss wants to color the shaded checkbox, i hope theres a way for that, i said to my sir "Sir please dont make Impossible,Possible" but he reply the I want you to do it :()

Comment: It can be done. Not in the way you made the whole cell red. Just make the checkbox Red.

Comment: Sir please last one help me do that :(

Comment: As I said before, you should not edit the post, it makes the answer useless and the question confusing. In the painting method after calling `CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox` use the code which I posted.

Comment: Its okay now sir no more editing post. TYSSSSSM for help. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `DataGridView`'s `VirtualMode` and then use `CellValueNeeded` event to display your own content.

Here is what I suggest you should do,

1. Decide an image to be displayed instead of checkbox (example a green tick)
2. Set the `DataGridView`'s `VirtualMode` property to `true`
3. After binding the `DataGridView` with your `DataTable` iterate through all month columns set the `DataProperptyName` as empty string (this important in order to trigger the event)
4. Create an event handler for `DataGridView`'s [`CellValueNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) event, in this event you will be receiving the Column Index and Row Index in event parameters. Use that to find the actual value behind and then return the green tick image (using `e.Value`) or return a blank image depending on the value.