# Change BackColor of DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn on Check or Uncheck

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

1- Add one DataGridView on Form1 and named it as DataGridView1.

2- Copy and paste following code into code behind.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim myColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn With {.ValueType = GetType(Boolean), .Name = "Option", .HeaderText = "Option"}
    myColumn.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(myColumn)
    For ii As Integer = 1 To 2
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add({True})
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Option" AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow = False Then
        If e.Value = False Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            'I tried following codes but they are not
            'DataGridView1.Refresh()
            'DataGridView1.Update()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

3- Run this project and uncheck one of the CheckBoxes.

I want to see red color as soon as I click CheckBox without delay.

Comment: Not sure, so just a comment, but try Invalidate() on the datagridview to force a re-paint.

Comment: Duplicate/repost of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54393561

Comment: @None of the Above  Puzzling duplicate :)

Comment: For those who look for a C# example to handle check change of `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`: [C# DataGridView Checkbox checked event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090635/3110834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these points to achieve changing back color of cell on check, and also removing selection highlight:

1. To push the checkbox value to cell, you need to handle `CellContentClick` and `CellContentDoubleClick` and using [`DataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) method to commit changes to cell value. Without doing this, the value will not push to the cell until after you end edit.
2. To make the selection back color invisible, you need to set `SelectionBackColor` of the cell to the same color as `BackColor`.

Then you can have something like this:

[image]

In the example, I've shown `False` as `Red`, `True` and `DbNull.Value` as `While`. You can change the logic based on your requirements. To achieve what you see in the animation, drop a `DataGridView` on the form and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("C1", GetType(Boolean))
    table.Columns.Add("C2", GetType(String))
    table.Rows.Add(True, "A")
    table.Rows.Add(False, "B")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick, DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick

    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        DataGridView1.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting

    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If TypeOf (e.Value) Is Boolean AndAlso e.Value = False Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    End If
    e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor
    e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = e.CellStyle.ForeColor
End Sub
```

**Note**

You can also use the solution which is described here:

- [Square Filled CheckBox in Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545988/3110834)

[image]